# Every "q'" press print something in Python

Tags: python, python-keyboard

Once I press "q" it prints this text many times. I want to print it once.

```
import keyboard

while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
            print('q pressed')
    except:
        break
```

Comment: With your script you have to keep q key pressed right ? You want to press q key single time and then print?. If so you can check python threading https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects

Comment: is_pressed will be triggered until and unless the key is released, its better you use `released`

Comment: Threading is also good idea, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is **constantly** repeating check until `q` is pressed, which is not cpu efficient, and also once the `q` is pressed `is_pressed` will always be `True` - it does not automatically reset.

There is a good example of what you want in [the docs](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#waiting-for-a-key-press-one-time). Do something like this:

```py
keyboard.wait('q')
print('q pressed, continue...')
```

Note that this will block execution until `q` is pressed, and will continue after that. If you want to repeat process, simply put it inside while loop:

```py
while True
    keyboard.wait('q')
    print('q pressed, waiting on it again...')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to break in your try clause after printing in order for loop to end, just like you did in except;

```
while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
            print('q pressed')
            break
    except:
        break
```

Comment: That works better, but i need to do this infinitely, for example: Q - print, Q - print, Q print etc

Comment: Do you still need that if so I can edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code repeats is that you do not check for when q is released. this causes the condition `if keyboard.is_pressed("q")` to run multiple times

to stop this. you need to check for when `q` is released

for example

```py
import keyboard

is_pressed = False

while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("q") && not is_pressed:
            print('q pressed')
            is_pressed = True:
        if not keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
            is_pressed = False

    except:
        break
```